# How to resolve Assembly Reference Error in VS2015?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2015

We built all our assemblies based on frameworks, maintain it in separate folders, and then configured it in Visual Studio. So, if I drag and drop a ‘Grid control’ in a designer page of a project with target framework as 4.6, all the dependency assemblies of the ‘Grid Control’ will be added under reference section with the assembly version related to 4.5.1 instead of assembly version related to 4.6 framework.

To be clear, see below

```
            Grid Control assembly version - 1.46.0.1 (4.6 framework)

            Dependent control assembly version – 1.451.0.1 (4.5.1 framework)
```

To refer the proper .NET Framework version in projects, we made the entry in following  registry location based on framework.

.NET Framework 4.6 à HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.5.23026\AssemblyFoldersEx\SES4.6

.NET Framework 4.5.1 à HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.5.1\AssemblyFoldersEx\SES4.5.1

Could anyone please help on this to get this error resolved?

PS: Please let us know where we missed to put the registry entry for .NET Framework 4.6 framework and do recommend us all possible solutions to try at our end.

Regards,

Vadivel

Comment: Please provide your prompt solution as this is very high priority one need to fix.

Comment: For more information, please refer the below link.   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73add5b0-f70d-43a9-b106-307ad403675d/whether-451-and-46-net-framework-assemblies-required-for-development?forum=wpf&prof=required